# Adding characters to a retrieve link with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Hi I want to extract and read some links (with beautifulsoup), but the webpage only puts [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGTam.png)
And I want to add the highlighted part to the link retrieve (at the beginning of the link).[the highlighted part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWnG9.png)
With the code I already have

Comment: I think you are looking for this [Python String Concatenation](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_string_concatenation.asp)

Comment: yep thanks now it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to concatenate the absolute link, you just need to do this:

```py
url = 'http://www.aduanet.gob.pe/' + x.lstrip('/')
```